# Outputting any Unicode text (not just specific languages)

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, font-encodings

My software uses `pdflatex` to generate PDF files that include text entered by users. This text can be in any language, so I need something like the following to "just work" with any arbitrary Unicode content:

```
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Öüä Эюя Tiếng Việt 日本語
\end{document}
```

I added the `T1` and `T2A` encodings, so European/Cyrillic languages should be fine now. I can add more, but according to [the CTAN guide](http://mirror.macomnet.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf), encodings for languages like Chinese are "experimental". The reliable way to output many languages seems to be to install and use additional packages specific to them, like `cjk`. Do I really need to go through the world's languages (sometimes one by one) and install whatever's out there?! Right now I'm tempted to just generate an image with the text and `\includegraphics` it, which may *actually be less ridiculous*.

**Can anyone suggest a better way?** I assumed a typesetting system used by academia around the world in 2016 would just have simple, sane support for Unicode. Don't see it right now.

Comment: Not with `pdflatex`: you're asking for ***gigantic*** work.

Comment: So what's the alternative? I just need a PDF file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're essentially asking for a huge enterprise without any real advantage. Even the idea of using pictures would require an enormous amount of work.

If you use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX with a font having wide Unicode coverage, you'll be home rather quickly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Code2000}

\begin{document}

Öüä Эюя Tiếng Việt 日本語

\end{document}
```

[image]